# Is there any sdk available for PayPal Payments Pro SDK in ios side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

It might be duplication, but I haven't find out proper solution (whatever I am looking for).

I am an iOS developer, currently I have an requirement to integrate PayPal Payments Pro SDK in ios side.

I already have knowledge about PayPal Standard SDK and I did it also. But how can I integrate PayPal Payment Pro (Credit card/ Debit Card Payments) in iOS side without taking PHP help (Server API).

I already generated Credentials like:

- API UserName
- API Password
- API Signature

I googled it a lot but I didn't find out proper solution regarding this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think it exists. You have to use:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK (Credit card/paypal payments).

Comment: I already told you PayPal Payment Pro is different than PayPal iOS SDK. I need to pay amount by using my custom UI Screen instead of presenting PayPal Payment Screen.